# Newtonsoft JSON find what Data model is in response

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using **RestClient** to call for **API** response. I'm getting the response and content in `queryResult.Content` correctly.

Depending on data I send in API body my response changes: for a set of data I may get model A, or I may get model B or Model C.

I want to know if there is any way to figure out what Model I'm getting in the JSON response.

- Model A

```json
{
   "status":"0",
   "error":{
      "error_":"GSP752",
      "message":"Error: AuthToken. Please call API"
   }
}
```

- Model B

```json
{
   "Status":"0",
   "Data":null,
   "ErrorDetails":[
      {
         "ErrorCode":"0",
         "ErrorMessage":"Duplicate"
      }
   ],
   "InfoD":[
      {
         "InfC":"DUPL",
         "Desc":{
            "AkNo":1561651,
            "AkDt":"2020-11-12 11:58:00",
            "Ir":"someKeyThatIcantShow"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Show some excerpts of the different json payloads, there maybe other ways to solve this. For instance they may just be subsets, or there is a chance you could use a base class and known types. ect, ect, ect ,ect ,ect

Comment: @TheGeneral question edited

Answer (score 1):

one option you might try would be to return type info along with the payload.
Since you mention `json.net` as your library of choice, you could try setting [`TypeNameHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm#TypeNameHandling) to `Objects` in serialization settings (exact config code will depend on your project so I can't be much more specific).

Having that field available, you would rely on it to further define processing logic on the client.